# Apache Drill problem reading parquet with UUID (RuntimeException: Unknown logical type <LogicalType UUID:UUIDType>)

Tags: uuid, parquet, apache-drill

[Running parquet-reader shows valid format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsK0M.png)

This is on Apache Drill 1.18.0, running on windows.

How do I get Drill to read parquet files with UUIDs in them.  I have a lot of these files.  Thank you in advance for any help or insight you can offer.

Comment: Could you share some examples to test? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for flagging this issue.  We opened a pull request to resolve this issue and it should be fixed soon!